# which file need to modify after seeing the result of command as echo $PATH and which flutter

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, path

I am installing the flutter using [Installation Link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux). To verify installation i checked following commands echo $PATH and which flutter. By mistake i have given the wrong path.

```
$ echo $PATH     
/home/harmony/flutter/bin:/home/harmony/anaconda3/bin:/home/harmony/bin:/home/harmony/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/harmony/flutter/bin
```

and

```
which flutter
/home/harmony/flutter/bin/flutter
```

I don't know which files are edited. Please help me to give correct path in both commands.

Thanks in Advance! Happy New Year folks!

Comment: You'll have to look through files to find out which ones you edited. Maybe ~/.bashrc? Look through the "[Update your path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path)" and "[Update path directly](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-path-directly)" sections of the document for other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228167/108618) on U&L SE. The main conclusion is

> There are many places where `PATH` can be set.

In your case a reasonable approach is to search `/etc/` and your home directory for a file that contains the erroneous string (which, I believe, is `:/harmony/flutter/bin`). It will be like:

```
grep -rl :/harmony/flutter/bin /etc/ ~/ 2>/dev/null
```

or (if your `grep` doesn't support `-r`):

```
find /etc/ ~/ -type f -exec grep -l :/harmony/flutter/bin {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Investigate files the command prints. If it prints anything mentioned in the linked answer then start from there. Hopefully you will find the right file. If not, try omitting the `:`.

While editing a startup script it's good to keep the old shell running. Edit the file and run new shells in various configurations (login, non-login, non-interactive). Verify if everything works (no infinite loops, no errors, `PATH` as expected or at least sane). If there are problems with new shells then use the old one to fix. Modified startup scripts cannot alter a shell started earlier, so the old shell should still be functional.

Answer (score -2):

$PATH : is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems that tells the shell which directories to search for executable files

which Flutter : open-source UI software development kit created by Google. It is used to develop applications for Android, iOS, Windows, Mac, Linux, Google Fuchsia and the web

Comment: -1, this does not answer the question asked.